# skipping spaces with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here i have a javascript/html code. My code is supposed to read a string of one or more zipcodes from the user and return the first non-valid zipcode. It should ignore spaces. the user can only use the zipcodes  48103, 48104, 48105, 48106, 48197, 48198. anything else should be invalid. My code mostly works except when the user puts in more than one space to separate the zipcodes. so for example if the user enters "48103, space , space, space, 98324" my program should return 98324 but it just returns the space. Can anyone help? Thank you

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Due 03/30</title>

        <script>

            function test()
            {   

                var usr = prompt("Enter a string of zip codes separated by spaces: ");
                var array = [];
                array = usr.split(" ");
                //alert (array);
                var pattern = /(4810[3-6])|(4819[7-8])/;
                var str;
                var isBad = false;

                var i;
                for (i =0; i < array.length; i++)
                {    
                    str = array[i];
                    if (!str.match(pattern) && str != " ")
                       {  
                          alert ("The zipcode " + str + " is not a valid zipcode!");
                          isBad = true;
                          break;
                       }
                }

                if (isBad === false)
                  alert("All zipcodes are valid");

               }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <button onClick="test();">Test String</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After splitting the string, loop through the array and remove blanks, not spaces.

Comment: It's `str != ""`. Without the space.

Comment: Or you get rid of the consecutive white space before doing your split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop:

```
for (i =0; i < array.length; i++)
{    
    str = array[i];
    if (!str.match(pattern) && str != " ")
       {  
          alert ("The zipcode " + str + " is not a valid zipcode!");
          isBad = true;
          break;
       }
}
```

Should be:(`str != ""` not `str != " "`)

```
for (i =0; i < array.length; i++)
{    
    str = array[i];
    if (!str.match(pattern) && str != "") // No space
       {  
          alert ("The zipcode " + str + " is not a valid zipcode!");
          isBad = true;
          break;
       }
}
```

This is because when you split the string: `"JavaScript is  Awesome!"` into spaces, then the javascript sees it as `"JavaScript"+Space+"is"+Space+""+Space+"Awesome!"`.

Comment: While my answer simplifies the problem (somewhat), this answer fully explains why the OP's code does not work.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Replace multiple spaces with single spaces within the split, using a regular expression:

```
array = usr.split(/ +/g);
```

(Thanks to @HBP for the edit.)

You can then replace this code:

```
if (!str.match(pattern) && str != " ")
```

… with:

```
if (!str.match(pattern))
```

Comment: `String.split` can also take RegExps as parameter so : `array = usr.split (/ +/)` should also work